# Map term indices to words in sparklyr ml_count_vectorizer

Tags: r, rstudio, apache-spark-mllib, lda, sparklyr

I cannot figure out how to map term indices produced by ft_count_vectorizer in sparklyr back to vocabulary words.  The output of lda models only has term indices, not words, so it is hard to make sense of the output without being able to map indices to words.  Example below.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

# connection
sc <- spark_connect(master = 'local')

# fake data
fake_data <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                        b = c("the groggy", "frog was", 
                              "a very groggy", "frog"))

fake_tbl <- copy_to(sc, df = fake_data, overwrite = TRUE)

# count vectorizer
fake_vectorizer <- fake_tbl %>%
  ft_tokenizer(input_col = 'b', output_col = 'tokens') %>%
  ft_count_vectorizer(input_col = 'tokens', output_col = 'features')

# model
fake_model <- fake_vectorizer %>%
  ml_lda(features_col = 'features', k = 2)

fake_model$topicsMatrix

# Which indices correspond to which words?
```